# ionic cordova encrypt base64 image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this app where I take picture with cordova camera  then move it into file-system , save the imgpath for the image into sqlite db and display it, I'm trying to encrypt the imgPath for the image which is saved on ccordova.file.data directory , I tried cordova safe plugin https://github.com/disusered/cordova-safe ,
but I keep getting "Error with cryptographic operation".

Any help would be appreciated

```
var db = null;
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']) 
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {    
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {      
            try {        
                db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({          
                    name: "my.db",
                              location: 'default'        
                });        
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imageTable " + "(id integer primary key, image text)");      
            } catch (e) {        
                alert(e);      
            } finally {       }

            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);


                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });
    })



    .controller('ImageCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $cordovaDevice, $cordovaFile, $ionicActionSheet, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, $cordovaDevice, $ionicPopup, $cordovaActionSheet, $cordovaSQLite, $interval) {




        var imagesP = [];

        //$scope.images = [];


        $scope.showAlert = function(title, msg) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: title,
                template: msg
            });
        };


        $scope.loadImage = function() {

            var options = {
                title: 'Select Receipts Image ',
                buttonLabels: ['Gallery', 'Take photo', 'File System'],
                addCancelButtonWithLabel: 'Cancel',
                androidEnableCancelButton: true,
            };
            $cordovaActionSheet.show(options).then(function(btnIndex) {
                var type = null;
                if (btnIndex === 1) {
                    type = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
                } else if (btnIndex === 2) {
                    type = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
                }
                if (type !== null) {
                    $scope.selectPicture(type);
                }
            });
        }




        // Take image with the camera or from library and store it inside the app folder
        // Image will not be saved to users Library.
        $scope.selectPicture = function(sourceType) {


            var options = {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: sourceType,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                correctOrientation: true,
                targetWidth: 800,
                targetHeight: 800,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions, // for IOS and IPAD
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };

            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
                    // Grab the file name of the photo in the temporary directory
                    var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                    //  alert(currentName);

                    //Create a new name for the photo to avoid duplication
                    var d = new Date(),
                        n = d.getTime(),
                        newFileName = n + ".jpg";
                    //alert(newFileName);
                    // If you are trying to load image from the gallery on Android we need special treatment!
                    if ($cordovaDevice.getPlatform() == 'Android' && sourceType === Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
                        window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath, function(entry) {
                            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(entry, success, fail);

                            function fail(e) {
                                console.error('Error: ', e);
                            }

                            function success(fileEntry) {
                                var namePath = fileEntry.nativeURL.substr(0, fileEntry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                                // Only copy because of access rights
                                $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, fileEntry.name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
                                    //  $scope.image = newFileName;
                                    var imgPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + newFileName;

                                    $scope.add(imgPath);
                               $scope.encryptFile(imgPath);




                                }, function(error) {
                                    $scope.showAlert('Error', error.exception);
                                });
                                //      alert( fileEntry.nativeURL);

                            };
                        });
                    } else {
                        var namePath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                        // Move the file to permanent storage
                        $cordovaFile.moveFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
                            // $scope.image = newFileName;
                            //$scope.images.push(newFileName);
                                    var imgPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + newFileName;
                            $scope.add(imgPath);




                        }, function(error) {
                            $scope.showAlert('Error', error.exception);
                        });

                    }
                },
                function(err) {
                    // Not always an error, maybe cancel was pressed...
                })
        };

        $scope.add = function(path) {             
                if (imagesP != null) {          
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "INSERT INTO imageTable (images) VALUES(?)", [path] );        
                }        
                alert("Inserted.");      
            },
            function(e) {        
                alert(e);      
            };

$scope.encryptFile = function(file){


            var safe = cordova.plugins.disusered.safe,
                key = 'someKeyABC';


            function success(encryptedFile) {
              console.log('Encrypted file: ' + encryptedFile);


            }

            function error() {
              console.log('Error with cryptographic operation');
            }

            safe.encrypt(file, key, success, error);
            }



          
        $scope.ShowAllData = function() {     
            $scope.images = [];      
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"SELECT images FROM imageTable").then(function(res) {          
                if (res.rows.length > 0) {            
                    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {              
                        $scope.images.push({                
                            id: res.rows.item(i).id,
                            image: res.rows.item(i).images

                                          
                        });            
                    }          
                }        
            },         function(error) {          
                alert(error);        
            }      );

             
        }
```

Comment: The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem. Streamline your example. **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears.

Comment: @georgeawg I tried the plugin with only a camera returned object , and it gave the same response